# In a spring bean, how to declare a variable of type ArrayList to serve concurrency

Tags: spring, concurrency

I'm trying to create a spring bean with a variable of type ArrayList. In this situation, Please suggest me what's the best option to define this variable to support concurrency without causing any issues while accessing the variable.

Here is my sample code.

> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import java.util.List; import
>
> org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> @Component
>
> public class MySpringBean {
>
> private List myListVar = new ArrayList<>();
>
> public List getMyListVar() {
>       return myListVar;   }
>
> public void setMyListVar(List myListVar) {
>       this.myListVar = myListVar;   }
>
> }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your spring bean in its current form and describe exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: @Kenster: I re-formatted my question. Let me add more details. My code flow is, For each call of a user, it has to read few DB records and do some processing on them and then set that output to the above List. And another method uses this list value by accessing it using getMyListVar() of the above bean. In this case, it's working fine when there is only one request but the list values are incorrect when firing 50 requests for 50 users at the same time. So, trying to understand, how can avoid this issue with concurrency with this list variable. Please suggest.

Comment: Concurrency won't help. Don't do things like this with a singleton. Make the bean request scoped to have a fresh instance per request. Or redesign your app to not use this class, but just pass parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum for the response. I'll try with 'request' scope for this bean